# Jquery replace text inside nested tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like <p> <b> old</b> </p>

I want to replace current text inside bold tag such that result is <p> <b> new</b> </p> tag when user clicks on the parent .

I am using jquery like `$(this > "b").text("new");` and `$(this).children("b").text("new");` but it is not working?

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: `$(this).children("b").text("new");` should work fine if you correctly get `<p>` element as `this`.

Comment: if your `<p>` contain only a `b` tag you can use children as this : `$(this).children().text("new");`. are you sure that `this` mean the `p` tag ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).find("b").html("new");
```

should do the trick, assuming there is a click handler on the `p` element.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvXZc/)

Find the child element by using `children()` method that is specified to your element - in this case `b`. For inner HTML content use `html()` method with the content you require specified.

Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/children/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

You can add an id to the P tag for the select and use something like this:

```
$("#p").children("b").text("new");
```

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zrvmk/